# Make array out of User ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using devise and a custom controller in Rails.

In a controller, I have:

```
def new
  @users = Users.where(store_id: 5)
  @array_of_users = []
end
```

In a view I have:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :employees, value: @users %>
```

Basically, I just want to get the employee ids and store them into an array, so if we have a user with id=50 and another with id=56, then store [50,56] in the hidden field.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
def new
  @users = Users.where(store_id: 5)
  @user_ids = @users.pluck(:id)
  @array_of_users = [] # no ides what is this for, so kept as it is.
end
```

Then inside the views :

```
<%= f.hidden_field :employees, :multiple => true, value: @user_ids %>
```

Comment: You should avoid having more than one instance variables per action. If you going to use `@users` anyway, it wouldn't be an overhead to just use `collect` instead of `pluck` in the `hidden_field` line.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the user ids directly from the database, it will return an array. If you convert the array into a string you will get something like this: [1,5,6,7]

```
def new
  @users = User.where(:store_id, 5).select("id")
end

<%= f.hidden_field :employees, value: @users.to_s %>
```